# Unity3d - Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/QCARWrapper.dll'

Tags: unity-game-engine, integration, vuforia

I want to use c++ dll on unity android application. To use native dll on a android device, I learn that I should use Unity 5. I download unity5 from [here](http://unity3d.com/get-unity). My application requires vuforia. So I download vuforia package from [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk).

Unity 5 is 64 bit.

On unity editor, I delete `MainCamera` and add `ARCamera`. There is an error message on unity console. The message is below :

```
Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/QCARWrapper.dll', expected 64 bit architecture (IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64), but was IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386.
Vuforia.WebCamAbstractBehaviour:CheckNativePluginSupport()
```

There is a solution for this problem on [vuforia forum](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/vuforia-40/unity-5). But I don't find `unity editor(32 bit)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use Vuforia with Unity 64 bit, just move the `QCARWrapper` DLLs from `/Plugins` to `/Plugins/x86`. These are the DLLs:

- QCARWrapper.exp
- QCARWrapper.lib
- QCARWrapper.dll
- QCARWrapper.dll.signature

This should solve the problem!

Comment: vuforia 5.5 contains VuforiaWrapper.dll instead QCARWrappper, move this and its related files into x86 folder as suggested) and don't forget to restart unity.

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://unity3d.com/get-unity/update    Under there, you will see **ADDITIONAL DOWNLOADS**  Under that you will see **FOR WINDOWS**. Click it and choose **Unity Editor (32-bit)**.

**EDIT**:
I see lots of **dowvotes**. This **was** the **ONLY** solution when this question was asked. **Unity 5 64bit** just got **released** when this question **WAS** asked and this was the **ONLY** solution back then. This answer was changed to the current answer that was provided **5 months** later when **Vuforia** released **64bit** version of their plugin.

Comment: You told him to install Unity 32bit along with his existing Unity 64 bit version to solve this?

Comment: Dude, read his question and then my answer before coming to a conclusion. He has a plugin problem and he found the solution. The solution was to install 32 bit Unity version but he couln't find the 32 bit version on Unity website. My answer provides a step on how to find it on Unity website.

Comment: Still **TODAY** that Unity 5+ is released, your answer **does** deserve a down-vote so that people don't see it as a good answer they should follow.

Comment: @Dimitris You are either naive or there is lack of comprehension in your side or maybe probably both. You think an answer that was the only solution available and solved the OP's problem at that time should be voted down?  A person with a common sense would look at the date in my answer then date in other answers and realize there wasn't any other answer around. Also, this answer is still useful for those who do not want to update their Vuforia plugin to 64 bit version. There are many answers on SO which are outdated but were helpful in the beginning. Should they all be down-voted too?

Comment: He needed Unity 32 bit version but couldn't find it so I provided the link and instructions on how to find it.

Answer (score 2):

**Vuforia 5.0** supports the **32bit** version of the Unity Editor on **Windows**, and the **64bit** version **on Mac**.

So, **There are two possible solutions:**

1. you just need to install and use the Unity 5 32bit Editor, on Windows.

***OR***

2. Create a new folder **"x86"** inside

   **Assets>>Plugins**

   inside your unity project structure
   Then move the following files from **"Plugins"** to newely created **"x86"** folder.

   - QCARWrapper.lib
   - QCARWrapper.dll
   - QCARWrapper.dll.signature
   - QCARWrapper.exp

After that check log message, If you see the log like:

```
Setting platform to 'Editor' for plugin: Assets/Plugins/x86/VuforiaWrapper.dll
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.ExtensionImport:UpdatePluginSettings() (at Assets/Vuforia/Editor/Scripts/ExtensionImport.cs:43)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

Then , **Congrats !! You are ready to Go!**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem /Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/QCARWrapper.dll'/ with vuforia plugin and latest version of Unity ( currently 5.1.2f 64bits ) and also couldn't get my laptop camera to work.

Everything is fixed with the 32 bit release of Unity, even if my os is 64 bits (Windows 7).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unity 5.1, make sure to set the right Graphics API settings in the Player Settings for Android and iOS:

disable the "Automatic Graphics API" checkbox
in the Graphics APIs list, make sure that only OpenGL ES 2.0 is included:
Android: remove OpenGL ES 3.0
iOS: remove OpenGL ES 3.0 and METAL

Important :
1. In your Unity project:

Select the QCARWrapper.bundle in the Unity Project view (located under Assets > Plugins ), so that its settings are shown in the Unity Inspector
Change the settings of QCARWrapper.bundle in the Unity inspector from "Any Platform" to "Standalone + Editor".

**Rebuild**

​OR:

2. In the Xcode project generated by Unity:

Go to Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources
Remove the QCARWrapper.bundle file from the list
**Rebuild**

My unity3d version is 5 and 64bit
,Os is Windows7 64 bit.

**my Problems solved** .

Edit :

Unity editor couldn't show laptop camera ,But **Rebuild**  Project , camera work .
 for example rebuild Android platform , and install .apk on device => application Ok .

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Name_Vuforia_Unity_Project\Assets\Plugins` and you will find `QCARWrapper.dll`.

Delete it and try again (could be necessary to restart unity).

Unity 64 bit