# Unity Vuforia custom image target at runtime

Tags: vuforia

I am new to Unity and I have a question.

Right now I am using Zxing to read a QR-Code in Unity. Getting the information from the QR-Code works fine, but I want my application to
show a plane 2D-Sprite right next to that scanned QR-Code. Of course this QR-Code should be tracked so the Sprite is always shown right
next to that QR-Code. The QR-Code changes after time to offer new information, the Sprite should change as well.

So my question ist: how do I track this QR-Code in runtime and show a 2D-Sprite next to it? any ideas?

I think i could use ImageTarget / User defined ImageTarget.

If anyone could help me, that would be awesome!

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Vuforia for this, you must have the exact QR code's image in the form of a Vuforia target. The Vuforia dataset you are using (generated via the Target Manager) must contain the specific QR codes you want to use. If you do not know them in advance, you can write a mechanism to download new datasets from a server during runtime and apply them. This is your main problem. Other than that, you will need to use Vuforia's Image Target integrated with Zxing. Perhaps this can help with that: [Unity Zxing QR code scanner integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546548/unity-zxing-qr-code-scanner-integration)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the problem with the link you posted: it shows an example for scanning the QR-Code. That's already works fine.
I need to track this QR-Code, and i need to define this QR-Code as an Image Target in runtime.
Maybe i oversee something?

Comment: OK Then you have no choice - with Vuforia, you must have a dataset that contains all the targets (QR codes, in your case) in order for this to work. What you can do, as I suggested, is update this dataset in runtime - you can  have your app download updated datasets from your server, and then apply them. Let me know if this is still not clear.