# Integrating Zxing with Vuforia in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, qr-code, barcode, zxing, vuforia

I am using Vuforia library for Augmented Reality in Unity.

I am trying to achieve support for AR Image Targets+ QR Codes+ Barcodes with Vuforia Library, Zxing (for QR and Barcodes) in Unity.

I couldn't figure out how Vuforia supports QR Codes and Barcodes using Zxing.Zxing is one of the proposed solutions for integrating with Vuforia I came across in some articles but there is no solution that how it integrates with Vuforia/Unity.

I googled, but couldn't find an exact solution/example/tutorial for what I need.

The link here [Unity Zxing QR code scanner integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546548/unity-zxing-qr-code-scanner-integration) seems to be related but the solution didn't work out.

As I am new to Unity can anyone please help me out?

Thanks in Advance!