# Image does not contain a definition for 'PIXEL_FORMAT'

Tags: unity-game-engine, zxing, vuforia, zxing.net

I've tried testing the c# code for a QR code reader in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546548/unity-zxing-qr-code-scanner-integration/30571186#30571186)

I just copy pasted the code into a C# script and placed it in the ARCamera prefab just like how the KDelli said but I've been getting this error:

> error CS0117: 'Image' does not contain a definition for 'PIXEL_FORMAT'

from these two lines:

```
private IEnumerator InitializeCamera() {
    var isFrameFormatSet = CameraDevice.Instance.SetFrameFormat(Image.PIXEL_FORMAT.RGB888, true);
}
private void Update() {
    var cameraFeed = CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraImage(Image.PIXEL_FORMAT.RGB888);
}
```

I think I just missed something like a `using` code/library or it might be due to the code being old that this error arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PIXEL_FORMAT` has been moved from `Image` to just `Vuforia`. So if you are importing Vuforia you can just use `PIXEL_FORMAT.RGB888` instead of `Image.PIXEL_FORMAT.RGB888`

For more information, you can find the latest API [here](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/reference/unity/namespaceVuforia.html#a8f7511b96bcb33bc2ea176a1a8dafb59)

Answer (score 1):

This helped me :

by changing `image.PIXEL_FORMAT` to just `PIXEL_FORMAT`

Thanks