# Error when trying to use DLL specific functions in Unity 5

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, import

I have imported a DLL into Unity, and I am confident it has imported successfully. I have defined a function on the DLL for Unity to use, however whenever it is called, Unity throws me a:

> DllNotFoundException: k8055d.dll

The DLL's function is defined through

```
[DllImport("k8055d")]
public static extern int Version();
```

and I get the error when this line is run:

```
Debug.Log (Version().ToString());
```

The reason I know it has found the DLL is that if I set the DLL to use both x64 and x86 architectures within the import settings, I get this error:

> Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/k8055d.dll', expected 64 bit architecture (IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64), but was IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386. You must recompile your plugin for 64 bit architecture.

But this error disappears when I set it to only use an x86 architecture within the import settings, the console just gives the DLLNotFoundException.

Information about the DLL can be found [here](http://www.intesiscon.com/ficheros/manuales-tecnicos/54-K8055-DLL-manual.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First google result for `IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386. You must recompile your plugin for 64 bit architecture.`  tells you to try to install and use the 32-bit version of Unity (Editor) to work with your 32 bit dll [(right here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119423/unity3d-failed-to-load-assets-plugins-qcarwrapper-dll).
Googling a second time for your specific dll ("`K8055D.DLL x64`") brings up a forum post where some people compiled your dll for x64 ([here](http://forum.velleman.eu/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8034), direct downloadlink [here](http://www.theo.ch/lazarus/K8055fpc64.zip)) and also interesting stuff going on [here](https://sites.google.com/site/pcusbprojects/4-velleman-experiment-board-k8055-pic-replacement/-full-32-bit-and-64-bit-dll-support-for-original-vellaman-k8055-and-k8055n-firmware). Hope this gives you some pointers.